Creation of black half size frame in the middle of a split video stream results in an FFmpeg error
The error was raised against the creation of black half size frame in the middle of a split video stream.
The purpose of this script is to shift the dual fisheye images up by 20 pixels.
This file splits a dual fisheye video into Left and Right, then crops each half 20 pixels down from top, then overlays onto 'black' half frame, then horizontal stacks the Left and Right images into new video OUT.mp4
@echo off
set "W=3840"    ::Width of video
set "H=1920"    ::Height of video
set "WC=1920"   ::Width of crop
set "HC=20"   ::Height of crop
set "X=0"       ::X coordinate of overlay
set "Y=0"       ::Y coordinate of overlay

ffmpeg -i %1 -filter_complex "split[left][right]; [left]crop=ih:iw/2:0:0[left_half];[right]crop=ih:iw/2:iw/2:0[right_half];[left_half]crop=%WC%:%H%-%HC%:0:%HC%[left_crop];[right_half]crop=%WC%:%H%-%HC%:0:%HC%[right_crop];color=black:size=%H%x%H%[bg];[bg][left_crop]overlay=%X%:%Y%:shortest=1[left_overlayed];[bg][right_crop]overlay=%X%:%Y%:shortest=1[right_overlayed];[left_overlayed][right_overlayed]hstack=shortest=1[out]" -y OUT.mp4
pause
::
::

The error message was:
The error is [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000207a61d4040] Invalid stream specifier: bg.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'bg' in filtergraph description split[left][right]; [left]crop=ih:iw/2:0:0[left_half];[right]crop=ih:iw/2:iw/2:0[right_half];[left_half]crop=1920:1920-20:0:20[left_crop];[right_half]
crop=1920:1920-20:0:20[right_crop];color=black:size=1920x1920[bg];[bg][left_crop]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[left_overlayed];[bg][right_crop]overlay=0:0:shortest=
1[right_overlayed];[left_overlayed][right_overlayed]hstack=shortest=1 matches no streams.


After you used [bg] to create an overlay it is consumed, you would have to use another [bg]split[bg1][bg2] if your intention is to use it twice.

The black half frame needs to be a separate input, this worked.
ffmpeg -i %1 -f lavfi -i color=black:size=%H%x%H% -filter_complex "[0]split[left][right]; [left]crop=ih:iw/2:0:0[left_half];[right]crop=ih:iw/2:iw/2:0[right_half];[left_half]crop=%WC%:%H%-%HC%:0:%HC%[left_crop];[right_half]crop=%WC%:%H%-%HC%:0:%HC%[right_crop];[1][left_crop]overlay=%X%:%Y%:shortest=1[left_overlayed];[1][right_crop]overlay=%X%:%Y%:shortest=1[right_overlayed];[left_overlayed][right_overlayed]hstack=shortest=1" -y OUT.mp4


In response to this comment:
After you used [bg] to create an overlay it is consumed, you would have to use another [bg]split[bg1][bg2] if your intention is to use it twice. –
Ricardo Bohner
This script did work:
ffmpeg -i %1 -filter_complex "split[left][right]; [left]crop=ih:iw/2:0:0[left_half];[right]crop=ih:iw/2:iw/2:0[right_half];[left_half]crop=%WC%:%H%-%HC%:0:%HC%[left_crop];[right_half]crop=%WC%:%H%-%HC%:0:%HC%[right_crop];color=black:size=%H%x%H%[bg0];[bg0][left_crop]overlay=%X%:%Y%:shortest=1[left_overlayed];color=black:size=%H%x%H%[bg1];[bg1][right_crop]overlay=%X%:%Y%:shortest=1[right_overlayed];[left_overlayed][right_overlayed]hstack=shortest=1" -y OUT.mp4

